# MessageQueueException The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msmq, send

My environment: Windows 7 Pro SP1

I created a private queue and am trying to send messages to that queue using an ASP.net MVC application. I get the error: MessageQueueException "The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation"

I've verified, in code, that the queue exists before attempting to send a message. I've given full-control to the queue for "EVERYONE" and "ANONYMOUS LOGON" using the queue properties' security tab.

I've looked at the existing threads and haven't found a solution yet.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm posting additional information: My computer is connected to a domain, but previously I installed MSMQ in workgroup mode. So, I corrected that (selected MSMQ Active Directory Domain Services Integration during install). My queue was created using LINQPad and I was trying to insert using a Visual Studio MVC application in debug mode. I tried with IIS local and IIS Express. I created the registry setting PermitAnonEveryoneSend = 1. My queue is defined as ".\private$\myQ". All of these changes didn't help. I still get the same error.

Comment: Some more information: If I create the queue through my ASP.net MVC application, I don't have any problem creating/inserting/reading/deleting the queue. So, why does it fail when I create the queue using LINQPad?

Comment: probably post some code and the exception detail, hard to say otherwise...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29225601/getting-the-queue-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-p